# Set default color of UI element

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Let's say I wanted to set the default onTintColor globally for all of my UISwitches to red. Is there a way to set it so when I choose "default" color in the storyboard, it will appear red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set appearance from your `appDelegate`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UISwitch.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this with Interface Builder, but consider using the `UIAppearance` class which can be used with most UI elements. For instance for `UISwitch` you would call:

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setOnTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This would make the tint color on all `UISwitch` instances to red. If you need to differentiate based on where you UI elements are you can use this code:

```
[[UISwitch appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyClass1 class], [MyClass2 class], nil] setOnTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This code only needs to be called once somewhere (for instance your app delegate) before the UI elements are created.

Comment: Question is all about swift language

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the swift tag. Although I actually disagree that it is about the Swift language at all. Rather, it is about the Cocoa Touch framework and the solution is the same regardless of the language used.

Comment: Ok @NobleK Hope other will get help from this. (Y)